# Lists in R: What is actually happening?

Tags: r

I can't figure out why R behaves the following manner.

```
integerList <- list(1:10)
integerList[[1]] # this works
integerList[[1:2]] # this works BUT WHY?
integerList[[1:3]] # this fails, as I would expect
```

Why does `integerList[[1:2]]` work (I think it should fail), but `integerList[[1:3]]` fails (as I think it should). When the last line of code fails, the error message is:

`Error in integerList[[1:3]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2`

Why? Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529145/lists-in-r-what-is-actually-happening#comment90026708_51529145) by 李哲源 says this:

> [[ can be applied recursively to lists, so that if the single index i is a vector of length p, alist[[i]] is equivalent to alist[[i1]]...[[ip]] providing all but the final indexing results in a list.

which is taken from the help page of `[[`. Try `` ?`[[` `` and look down the page.

What this means is that `integerList[[1:2]]` is equivalent to `integerList[[1]][[2]]`, which returns `2` (since it is the second element of the vector in the first element of the list). Obviously `2` has no third element, so `integerList[[1:3]]` (which is `integerList[[1]][[2]][[3]]`) fails.

Answer (score 1):

In `integerList[[1:2]]` you are asking for the second element of the list that is nested within the first element of `integerList`. A vector is just a special list in R, so this returns the second element, which is 2.

In `integerList[[1:3]]` you are asking for the third element of the second element of the list that is nested within the first element of `integerList`. This element clearly doesn't exist, hence the error.

---

To further demonstrate, two more examples:

#### Example 1

```
integerList[[c(1, 3)]]
#[1] 3
```

Here we are accessing the 3rd element of the first element of `integerList`.

#### Example 2

```
integerList2 <- list(list(1:10, 11:20))
integerList2
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
#
#[[1]][[2]]
# [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

integerList2[[1:3]]
#[1] 13
```

Here we are accessing the third element of the second element of the first element of `integerList2`.

Answer (score 0):

`integerList[[1:2]]` is the same as `integerList[[1]][[2]]` i.e. the second element of the first element of `integerList`

`integerList[[1:3]]` is the same as `integerList[[1]][[2]][[3]]` i.e. the third element of the second element of the first element of `integerList`

Try

```
integerListoflists <- list(list(111:119,121:125),201:207)
integerListoflists[[1]][[2]][[3]]
integerListoflists[[1:3]]
```

to get both times

```
[1] 123
```

while both of

```
integerListoflists[[1]][[2]]
integerListoflists[[1:2]]
```

give

```
[1] 121 122 123 124 125
```